# How To Create An HDF4 Package For Julia?

Tags: julia, hdf5, hdf

EDIT:

### My co-workers want me to create an interface for Julia and HDF4 because they're working on satellite technology that already works with HDF4. I also need to learn how a C packages library is interfaced to Julia.

I tried entering the command Pkg.add("hdf4") to the terminal, but it doesn't work. I even tried checking the JuliaIO GitHub page, but I can only find a package for HDF5 (not 4).
I'd appreciate the help.
(I'm pretty sure Julia supports HDF4.)

Comment: I'm rather certain nobody has written a public HDF4 library for Julia.  What makes you think Julia supports it?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a bespoke julia package for HDF4. Your options are either running a system command via julia, or using one of julia's available language interfaces to import your data via another language (e.g. c / java / python)

Comment: @MattB. This is why I thought there was an HDF4 library for Julia: https://ediscoverypeople.com/esi/file-types/multi-domain/hdf4-hdf5

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I don't understand your comment. I'm still new to programming, Julia, and HDF4. :-(

Comment: @MCTan ok, well, if you'd like to link to an example hdf4 file and a _simple_ operation which describes what you'd like to do with it in julia (e.g. import, get image data, whatever; as long as it's not something like "can you solve the multidimensional scaling problem on this dataset for me kthxbye" :p ) then I'd be happy to try and figure out a basic workflow for you to get you started :)

Comment: @MCTan also, I'm sure you've already looked into this yourself but it's worth confirming; are you _sure_ you're after hdf4 and not hdf5? As you're discovering yourself, it's far less common than its hdf5 counterpart. What is your exact use-case; care to provide some background?

Comment: I'm trying to make an HDF4 package for Julia. Any advice on how to approach this? I'm looking at the HDF5 package in GitHub as reference.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Yes, I'm pretty sure that I'm supposed to work with HDF4. My co-workers want HDF4, not HDF5, because they have technology that runs with HDF4. They don't want to update it to HDF5.

Comment: Regarding your updated question: interfacing with C is fairly straightforward. Here is the relevant page in the julia docs: https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/ . If you already have some c code which works, then hopefully it should be fairly straightforward to call that in the way described.